# Confused about using memcache and compare which solution is better

Tags: php, memorycache

First explain the situation I encountered.

There is an api `getToken` about access third party resources,
it will generate token and expired time of token.

Response like:

```
  token
  expired_time
```

We hope to prevent 429 (too many request) error by setting the cache.

And we have two version.

**version 1**

```
$cache = $memcache->get($cacheKey);
if ($cache) {
  return $cache['token'];
}


// Same as code 2.
$tokenResponse = $this->getToken();
$ttl = strtotime($tokenResponse['expired_time']) - strtotime('now');
if ($ttl > 0) {
    $memcache->set($cacheKey, $tokenResponse, $ttl);
} else {
    throw new Exception('error');
}

return $httpResponse['token'];
```

**version 2**

```
$cache = $memcache->get($cacheKey);
if ($cache) {
  $ttl = strtotime($cache['expired_time']) - strtotime('now');
  if ($ttl > 0) return $cache['token'];
  $memcache->delete($cacheKey);
}

// Same as code 1.
$tokenResponse = $this->getToken();
$ttl = strtotime($tokenResponse['expired_time']) - strtotime('now');
if ($ttl > 0) {
    $memcache->set($cacheKey, $tokenResponse, $ttl);
} else {
    throw new Exception('error');
}

return $httpResponse['token'];
```

My friend told me that version2 is better.

But I'm confusing about `$memcache->delete($cacheKeyName);` part.

Why do I need to calculate the ttl and delete the key specifically if the memcache is already expired the key？

Comment: First thing I would do is ask your friend why they make the comment, see what reasons they have for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the ttl correctly in memchache, it won't return the value after the expire time. So, there is no need to delete it since there is nothing there to delete! I don't know your code's exact logic but this should work:

```
$cache = $memcache->get($cacheKey);
if (!$cache) {
  $tokenResponse = $this->getToken();
  $ttl = strtotime($tokenResponse['expired_time']) - strtotime('now');
  $memcache->set($cacheKey, $tokenResponse, $ttl);
  return $tokenResponse['token'];
}
return $cache['token'];
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion let me know that my suspicion is right.